# How to fit the paper-size to the content in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I'd like to create a pdf/ps/eps that contains only one single formula.
I thought the easiest way would be to use latex.
Unfortunately, I found no option to specify, that the paper-size should automatically be set to fit the contents.

I found that dvipng has a "-T tight" option, that actually does the trick, but...
I want it in vector-graphics format.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

With the standalone class, you get exactly what you want.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\[
   x + y = z
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: IMNSHO, this is the best answer; it's pure LaTeX, it doesn't rely on cranky external programs, and it's modern and up-to-date, and can be used with modern TeX processors like pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaLaTeX. I have no idea why some "challenged person" downvoted you, and I apologise on his behalf for the whole thinking TeX community. +1

Comment: Yes, the best answer indeed.
And with 
\documentclass [border = 2pt] {standalone}
, there would be no cropping of your tables and diagrams.

Comment: Perfect. Please add bounty.. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Try [pdfcrop](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/pdfcrop/), it crops your pdf to the minimum. You need to have Perl installed.

Answer (score 1):

for Mac, there is a little app called LaTeXit which does exactly that. http://chachatelier.fr/programmation/latexit_en.php

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the bounding box of generated EPS should help:

```
epstopdf --gsopt=-dEPSCrop blah.eps
```

or `eps2pdf` has a `-B` option that detects the tightest possible Bounding Box.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat perversely, you can generate your Tex using Metapost: include your formula between btex and etex tags, and compile it following the instructions in either mptopdf(1) (prefered, part of pdftex) or mpost(1) (you'll need to run Tex separately as well, I think).  It is perverse to invoke Metapost just to have it invoke Tex, but it you will get formula-sized output without any evil pdf hackery.

If you need any Latex (as opposed to plain Tex), then you need a bit of boilerplate to get this to work, cf. [LaTeX labels in MetaPost](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/metapost/2006-January/000489.html).